# git archive - Multiple gits

Tags: git

I am using `git archive` with `--remote` option to archive multiple gits ,are located under one folder. I want to include those folder names of four gits and if .gitattributes is available in those gits that should also be taken care during the archive.

With `git archive --worktree-attributes --prefix=source --remote` command I didn't get the expected output.

How do I achieve this archive ?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a similar script than [**git-archive-all**](http://github.com/meitar/git-archive-all.sh/blob/master/git-archive-all.sh), which builds an archive file(s) of all git repositories and submodules in a current *local* path.
It needs to be completed to take into account a remote path.